# ¿como obtener datos en una sola consulta en base a una lista? LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

obtengo una lista que contiene el nivel de acceso a una solicitud y quiero obtener una lista de solicitudes que tienen es nivel.

al retornar "return vrequest.AsEnumerable().ToList();" me da este error No se puede crear un valor de constante de tipo 'SistemaControlGastos.ModeloBD.CatNivel'. Solo se admiten tipos primitivos o tipos de enumeración en este contexto.

entonces en la parte del where tendria que cambiar para hacer la condicion que cumpla la lista de niveles

```
    public List<object> getRequestGerent()
    {
             List<CatNivel> listNivel = Authweb.listNivel.Where(x => x.tipo == "primary").ToList();
             var vrequest = (from trequest in Context.Request
                        where listNivel.Any(cn => cn.nivel == trequest.position)
                        select new
                        {
                            idRequest = trequest.IdRequest,
                            requestDate = trequest.nRequesition.requestDate,
                            cantidad = (from tpd in Context.Product
                                        where tpd.FKReq == trequest.IdRequest
                                        select tpd.totalMount).ToList().Sum(),
                            status = trequest.nRequesition.status,
                            nivel = trequest.position,
                            cCot = (from tc in Context.Cotizacion
                                    where tc.FKRequest == trequest.IdRequest
                                    select tc).Count(),
                            categoria = trequest.nRequesition.categoria
                        });
        return vrequest.AsEnumerable<object>().ToList();
    }
```

ejemplo

en este es lo que quiero hacer pero en una sola consulta

```
var rProvidier = Context.regProvider
                                .Where(x => x.FKRequest.Equals(vrequest.IdRequest))
                                .ToList();
        List<CatProvider> lcp = new List<CatProvider>();
        for (int i = 0; i < rProvidier.Count; i++)
        {
           lcp.Add(getProvider(rProvidier[i].FKCatProvider));
        }
    public CatProvider getProvider(int idp)
    {
        var cp = (from tp in Context.CatProvider
                  where tp.IdProvider == idp
                  select tp).FirstOrDefault();
        return cp;
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fijate que tenes un ToList().sum() y un count sin ToList() no recuerdo cual de los 2 está mal pero me parece que el tolist().sum()

debería quedar así

```
public List<object> getRequestGerent()
{
   var listNivel = 
         Authweb.listNivel.Where(x => x.tipo == "primary").select(x => x.nivel).ToList();
         var vrequest = (from trequest in Context.Request
         where listNivel.Contains(trequest.position)
                    select new
                    {
                        idRequest = trequest.IdRequest,
                        requestDate = trequest.nRequesition.requestDate,
                        cantidad = (from tpd in Context.Product
                                    where tpd.FKReq == trequest.IdRequest
                                    select tpd.totalMount).Sum(),
                        status = trequest.nRequesition.status,
                        nivel = trequest.position,
                        cCot = (from tc in Context.Cotizacion
                                where tc.FKRequest == trequest.IdRequest
                                select tc).Count(),
                        categoria = trequest.nRequesition.categoria
                    });
    return vrequest.AsEnumerable<object>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: Puede ser pero no me causa conflicto necesito que me traiga los registros que tienen el mismo valor valor de de la lista

Comment: var vrequest = (from trequest in Context.Request
         where listNivel.Any(cn => cn.nivel == trequest.position) esta mal
var vrequest = (from trequest in Context.Request
         where listNivel.Contains(cn => cn.nivel == trequest.position)

Comment: dice error de sintaxis contains no puede recibir lambad solo CatNivel

Comment: listNivel debe ser una lista/array del valor a comparar en este caso nivel.
var listNivel = 
         Authweb.listNivel.Where(x => x.tipo == "primary").Select(x => x.nivel).ToList();
ahora si se puer aplicar el contains        
 var vrequest = (from trequest in Context.Request
         where listNivel.Contains(trequest.position)

espero que con esto funcione, corrijo respuesta arriba

Answer (score 0):

Sí, en la `where` deberías comprobar que en `listNivel` existe algún elemento con `nivel` igual al valor de la propiedad `position`:

```
List<CatNivel> listNivel = Authweb.listNivel.Where(x => x.tipo == "primary").ToList();
var vrequest = (from trequest in Context.Request
                where listNivel.Any(cn=> cn.nivel==trequest.position)
                select new
                {
                    idRequest = trequest.IdRequest,
                    requestDate = trequest.nRequesition.requestDate,
                    cantidad = (from tpd in Context.Product
                                where tpd.FKReq == trequest.IdRequest
                                select tpd.totalMount).ToList().Sum(),
                    status = trequest.nRequesition.status,
                    nivel = trequest.position,
                    cCot = (from tc in Context.Cotizacion
                            where tc.FKRequest == trequest.IdRequest
                            select tc).Count(),
                    categoria = trequest.nRequesition.categoria
                });
```

Comment: me dio error este  LINQ to Entities no reconoce el método 'Boolean Exists(System.Predicate`1[SistemaControlGastos.ModeloBD.CatNivel])' del método, y este método no se puede convertir en una expresión de almacenamiento.

Comment: Cierto, prueba con `Any`. Lo modifico en la respuesta.

Comment: al retornar "return vrequest.AsEnumerable<object>().ToList();" me da este error No se puede crear un valor de constante de tipo 'SistemaControlGastos.ModeloBD.CatNivel'. Solo se admiten tipos primitivos o tipos de enumeración en este contexto.